# Convert specific value in array of objects to lowercase

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to convert every value of a specific key in an array of objects to lowercase. For example I want to lowercase every value with the key 'Domain':

```
var array = [
   { "Name" : "Bill":,
     "Domain" : "TEST.com",
   },
   { "Name" : "John":,
     "Domain" : "JohnTest.com",
   },
   { "Name" : "Fred":,
     "Domain" : "fredtest.com",
   }
]
```

Would convert to:

```
var newArray = [
   { "Name" : "Bill":,
     "Domain" : "test.com",
   },
   { "Name" : "John":,
     "Domain" : "johntest.com",
   },
   { "Name" : "Fred":,
     "Domain" : "fredtest.com",
   }
]
```

I know how to use the `toLowerCase()` with strings and arrays, but I can't seem to figure out how to map over an array of objects to do this. I was trying something along the lines of this:

```
var newArray = array.map(function(i) {
    return i.Domain.toLowerCase;

})
```

Comment: Do you want to mutate the original objects or fill the new array with (deep-)copies?

Comment: Sorry I'm not completely sure what you mean, I'm fairly new to javascript. I just want the exact same array returned, just with lowercase domains. It doesn't necessarily have to be put into it's own new array

Comment: This works, but the answer from @mersocarlin has the advantage of working with objects with many more properties, without changing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map like this:

```
var newArray = array.map(function(elem, i) {
    return {
        Name: elem.Name,
        Domain: elem.Domain.toLowerCase()
    };
});
```

When you used the `array.map` function, your first parameter on the inside function was `i`, but hopefully you can understand via my example that the first parameter is actually the element in the array, and the 2nd parameter is the 'index'.

Comment: No problem @MattMcCode. And for your information, the objects in your arrays looks like they have too many `:` symbols :)

Answer (score 5):

[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns another array and since each item of your array is an object you need to return an object on each iteration as well:

```js
const array = [
   { "Name" : "Bill:",
     "Domain" : "TEST.com",
   },
   { "Name" : "John:",
     "Domain" : "JohnTest.com",
   },
   { "Name" : "Fred:",
     "Domain" : "fredtest.com",
   }
]

const result = array.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  Domain: item.Domain.toLowerCase()
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Best answer here!

Comment: This is `es6` and will not work if not transpiled with `babel`.

Answer (score 0):

Your object structure has some syntax errors. But after fixing them, you can just enumerate the objects in the array and reset the `Domain` property to the lowercase version.

```js
var array = [
   { "Name" : "Bill",
     "Domain" : "TEST.com"
   },
   { "Name" : "John",
     "Domain" : "JohnTest.com"
   },
   { "Name" : "Fred",
     "Domain" : "fredtest.com"
   }
]

// Enumerate the array items
array.forEach(function(obj){
  // Set the Domain property of the current object being enumerated
  // to the lowercase version of itself
  obj.Domain = obj.Domain.toLowerCase();
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks Scott! I was really overthinking it.

Comment: @MattMcCode You're welcome. Don't forget to mark this as "the" answer and up vote all helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all delete ":" after every value in object.
Second you should call toLowerCase method by "()"

```
function mapper(array) {
      return array.map(function(i) {
         i.Domain = i.Domain.toLowerCase();
         return i;
    })
}

var array = [
   { "Name" : "Bill",
     "Domain" : "TEST.com",
   },
   { "Name" : "John",
     "Domain" : "JohnTest.com",
   },
   { "Name" : "Fred",
     "Domain" : "fredtest.com",
   }
]

var newArray = mapper(array);

console.log(newArray); /*[ { Name: 'Bill', Domain: 'test.com' },
    { Name: 'John', Domain: 'johntest.com' },
    { Name: 'Fred', Domain: 'fredtest.com' } ]*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var newArray = [
    {
        "Name": "Bill",
        "Domain": "TesT.com",
    },
    {
        "Name": "John",
        "Domain": "Tohntest.com",
    },
    {
        "Name": "Fred",
        "Domain": "FredTe`enter code here`st.com",
    }
]

newArray = newArray.map(function (data) {
    return {
        Name: data.Name,
        Domain: data.Domain.toLowerCase().trim()
    }
})

console.log(newArray)
```

you can try this way